# python stdout carriage return

Tags: python

i am running a for loop on a given set of files..and for monitoring purpose it writes output on which files are being currently processed..

```
sys.stdout.write("\rProcessing.... "+ j)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

where j is filenames

output of script...

```
Processing.... /etc/sysconfig/rhn/sources0.examplewn-slepcsbals-ipv6f
```

problem is that the carriage return "\r" does not clear the previous filename clearly and has previous filenames on it.

any idea how i can fix this..and make it more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remember the written string, and write spaces first.

```
sys.stdout.write('\r' + (' ' * len(old_string)))
sys.stdout.write('\rProcessing... ' + new_string)
```

Comment: `sys.stdout.write('\rProcessing... ' + new_string + (' ' * (len(old_string) - len(new_string)))) would be enough...